# How to can i add emoji in text using emoji library?

Tags: android, textview

I want to add an emoji to a predefined text view. User no need to change that.
How can i achieve this

"Hi there !"

in TextView

in Android using emoji library ?
Do i need to use emoji library ?

Comment: You can try this `compile "com.android.support:support-emoji:27.1.1"`  source https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a library for this.

**`Method 1`**

Suppose you have a textview, then try this

```
textView.setText(new String(Character.toChars(0x1F60A)));
```

where `0x1F60A` is the unicode for your smiley

**`Alternate Method`**

add this resource in `strings.xml`

`<string name="smiley_text">&#x1F60A;</string>`

then add it to textview like below

```
textview.setText(R.string.smiley_text);
```

Comment: Thank You ..now i know how to do this !!

Comment: Adding to xml is the question, however in order to properly display on device you do need the EmojiCompat library if target version is an older one. Besides older android versions might throw an exception for some characters in xml.

Answer (score 3):

- Check this library https://github.com/vanniktech/Emoji

  ```
  implementation 'com.vanniktech:emoji-ios:0.5.1'
  ```
- Add this line to `onCreate` inside Application class.

  ```
  EmojiManager.install(new IosEmojiProvider()); // This line needs to be executed before any usage of EmojiTextView, EmojiEditText or EmojiButton.
  ```
- Then use `EmojiEditText` & `EmojiTextView`

  ```
  <com.vanniktech.emoji.EmojiTextView
      android:id="@+id/emojiTV"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  ```

**Update**

- Use [EmojiCompat](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/emoji-compat)

  - Open the build.gradle file of your application.
  - Add the support library to the dependencies section.

    ```
    dependencies {
          ...
         compile "com.android.support:support-emoji:27.1.1"
    }
    ```
  - Use EmojiCompat widgets in layout XMLs. If you are using AppCompat, refer to the Using EmojiCompat widgets with AppCompat section.

    ```
    <android.support.text.emoji.widget.EmojiTextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    ```

**Update 2**

- For **predefined** emojis you can use [unicode emojis](https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html), as **Navneet Krishna** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51238925/1283715).

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
int unicode = 0x1F60A;
```

Which can be used with

```
public String getEmojiByUnicode(int unicode){
return new String(Character.toChars(unicode));
```

}

So Textview displays  without Drawable

Reference link:http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem with:

```
Html.fromHtml()
```